# Iteration over an array and passing classList with a separate delay

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

im still noob in programming and need some help. In code below im trying to achive animation on every item of array with delay between passing classList to each element of an array. So far i have animation on each letter playing separately, but class ' offer-animation' is added to every item at the same time. I can't figure out how to add delay to toggling the class.

```
const letters = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')]


const offerAnimation = () => {
    let delayTime = 1

    letters.forEach(item => {
        item.classList.toggle('offer-animation')
        item.style.animationDelay = '.' delayTime + 's'
        item.style.color = 'lime'
        
        delayTime++
        
    })
} 
offerAnimation()
```

I tried setInterval(), but failed miserably.

Comment: [wanting to do something without firstly passing time to learn how to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Is the delay, and the CSS animation to be treated separately? For example the CSS animation would fade in a letter over 0.2s but you want to add a delay to that animation happening for each letter?

Comment: I'll try to explain more accurately - i want to add delay to passing css class with classList.toggle. For now code above adds class 'offer-animation' to every array item at the same time. What i need is mechanism to pass this class to one item at a time for animation duration ( 1s), then remove it from 1st item and pass it to second item and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue you have to use async/await and delay.

First of all you need Promise based delay function.

```
    function delay(delayInMs) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
         setTimeout(resolve, delayInMs)
      })
    }
```

Then upgrade your code to make it work with async/await

```
const offerAnimation = async () => { // added async flag here
    let delayTime = 1
    
    for(let item of letters) { // Converted forEach construction to regular  loop in order to maintain subsequence
      item.classList.toggle('offer-animation');
      item.style.animationDelay = '.' delayTime + 's'
      item.style.color = 'lime'

      const delayInMs = delayTime * 1000 // converting seconds to milliseconds
      await delay(delayInMs); // here we waiting for delay

      delayTime++;
    }
}
```

To read more about async/await check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-async-await-tutorial-learn-callbacks-promises-async-await-by-making-icecream/) or feel free to find own resource to read about it :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunatelly @chesterkmr i tried Your solution, but it didn't sloved my problem :( i tweaked code a little bit  -> https://codepen.io/xLaufey/pen/QWxveOE         it works almost as intended, but dunno why setInterval isnt working to fire animation again.

Comment: I updated your codepen with my snippet.Take a look https://codepen.io/chesterkmr/pen/PoaabyE

Regarding your issue with setInterval,it doesnt fire animation again because you clearing interval in setTimeout.

Comment: https://codepen.io/xLaufey/pen/QWxveOE      This is what I came up with after experimenting, and it works as i wanted to but i feel like this code slows down whole browser, i don't know if code under link is made with good practices. Your code also wroks @chesterkmr, but animation loop don't repeat itself, and is jumping on each letter slower :P

Comment: @Mixol456 i suggest you to convert setInterval to recursive setTimeout.